# error in running pig script in tez mode with hacatalog

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog, bigdata

I was running a `pig` script with `tez` as the execution engine and using `hcatalog`. Below is my pig script.

```
 set exectype=tez;
    a = load 'hive table' using org.apache.pig.hcatalog.hive.HCatloader();
```

when I entered the following in command line,

```
pig -useHCatalog -x tez /home/script.pig
```

I got an error:

> "error encountered during parsing " ";" "; " at line1, column 17.

Can anyone tell me what the issue is. Is there any different way to set execution engine inside a script?

Comment: exectype=tez generally goes into conf/pig.properties right?

Comment: according to the below link it can be coded in pig script as well. http://pivotalhd.docs.pivotal.io/docs/pig-tez.html

Comment: can you show us the code of what's inside the script.pig file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
set exectype tez
```

instead of :

```
set exectype=tez;
```

And anyway, isn't specifying "-x tez" enough to set the execution type? Why do you need to add it in the script as well?